# Responsive media queries not working in css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am  working on site ,and implement responsive design on it ,and i am new to this, and using
`http://resizemybrowser.com/` for testing my site,
 Everything is working fine on when i resize my browser(chrome)  like header,middle ,footer part resize  on the browser window except only Main middle part of site is not working well after 757px , the css style for main part is " .hero " and style with main style: 
 `.hero {width: 930px;color: #444;margin: 0 auto;}` And media queries for .hero is 
`@media (max-width: 979px).hero {width: 750px;color: #444;margin: 0 auto;}` 
 `@media (max-width: 767px).hero {width: 650px;color: #444;margin: 0 auto;}` 
  and as same for Max `width:1200px` , max `width:480px` etc ...
the problem is .hero main part is not responsive After `width of 757px`  always shows that `.hero   width is  750px` while the browser window on `320 , 480 ,640 ,720 px` and after that  on other width like (800 ,960,1024,1280,1366 px ) gives good responsive result & .hero width changes.
I am stuck on this main part , please figure out some solution for that ,,, thanks in advance

Comment: set a min-width for .hero

Comment: You need to provide more of the markup (html) in order to answer this effectively.

Comment: you forgot the breckets in the queries

Comment: ok ,,,,i got it ,,,, bracket error ....solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your media query needs another brackets, like here:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .hero {
        width: 750px;
        color: #444;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnaks ,@michal ,u are life saver...i checked numerous times and find  no error.